# python popen.communicate() with multiple stdin writes

Tags: python, stream, stdout, pipe, stdin

I have an external process that i am trying to trigger from python and then send information to via Popen.stdin.communicate(). The process I'm talking to writes a few lines to stdout then prompts the user for input via stdin (a number) it then writes a few ore lines and prompts for a second input via stdin. I want to replace the manual input with a python script that will automate this for me. So far i have the following code which does a good job of submitting the first round of user input:

```
working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
working_file.communicate(input=b'3')[0]
```

The subprocess behaves as expected and then it prompts for the second input, unfortunately communicate() doesnt seem to let you write more than once to the stdin. The next thing i tried was replacing the previous line with this:

```
working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
working_file.stdin.write(b'3')
working_file.stdin.write(b'7')
```

I get no errors so presumably the data is going somewhere, but the subprocess isn't getting the data (i know this because when it receives that data it writes to a log file). Obviously im not understanding something, I'd like to undestand better what communicate() is doing behind the scenes so that i could find an alternative method for writing to stdin but i have found the docs on this object a bit hard to understand. I'm also no expert on buffers and streams so that is tripping me up.

Could anyone shed any light on how the comunicate object works and how i might be able to do somethign similar but with multiple writes. Also does anyone know where is a good place to read up on streams and buffers?

Many thanks

jon

Answer (score 0):

As per python's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.

Comment: Hi there, just changed the post to show the creation of the subprocess with the PIPE attribute, i think i did that right, im assuming so as the communicate() object will works and shouldnt work unless stdin=PIPE is present, jt